# trim not working for ajax send? $_POST

Tags: php, ajax

```
$name = trim(&$_POST['name']);
```

why trim this way would not work? I was following a tutorial, it put & sign before `$_POST['name']` which I was not sure what is that for.. I got an error when it is $name = `$_POST['name']`;

this is the following lines of code

```
if($name && $email && $password && $cpassword){
        mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","") or die("Fail to connect to database");
        mysql_select_db("reglog");

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(username,email,password) VALUES('$name','$email','$cpassword')");
        echo 1;
}else{
    echo "not allowed"; 
}
```

by using     `$name = trim(&$_POST['name']);`

I dont get the 1 value return to my ajax data

here is my js

```
$("#send").click(function(){
    var all = $("form").serialize();
    if(validateName() & validateEmail() & validatePass1() & validatePass2() == true){
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "insert.php",
            data: all,
            success: function(data){
                if(data==1){
                    alert("success, you have registered");
                }else{
                    alert('Validate your form with correct informations to proceed!');
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: what error did you get for $_POST['name'];

Comment: maybe it's because I don't use a form submit to send the data, I was using merely a button then bind with ajax to send

Comment: Because `$_POST['name']` is empty .

Comment: @davidkonrad is that because I send through ajax ? I tried to send via form submit, $name = $_POST['name'] wont hv any error

Comment: can you show your code you use for $.ajax({...}); as well..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you use  `$("form").serialize()`, you create string in format like this:

```
a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4&e=5&name=some_name
```

So to get `name` in PHP side you need to do domething like:

```
$data = array();
parse_str($_POST, $data)
//do
print_r($data);// to see how you get the `POST` data
```

or use `$('form').serializeArray()`, like

```
var all = $("form").serializeArray();
```

and in PHP

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

What error did you get when u used $name = trim($_POST['name']);

The syntax is perfect.

Comment: this is a comment not an answer

Comment: it just don't work..

if($name && $email && $password && $cpassword){
  mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","") or die("Fail to connect to database");
  mysql_select_db("reglog");

  mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(username,email,password) VALUES('$name','$email','$cpassword')");
  echo 1;
}else{
 echo "not allowed"; 
}

the ajax callback function does not get the 1 value..

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to try and always use `isset()` first to avoid errors:

```
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? trim($_POST['name']) : 'Some other value';
```

Personally I think it's kinda lame when you get an error, especially if `$_POST['name']` **is** set. But whatever. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The `&`, in PHP, is for arguments passed by reference into a function, so that the value passed changes outside the function like:

```
$whatever = 0;
function referWhat(&$arg){
  $arg = 10;
}
referWhat($whatever);
```

Now `$whatever === 10`.

Comment: what if outside there is more than 1 variable that hv the sign of & in front?

Comment: You should remove `&` in front of `$`, if it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

try checking variable set or not with empty()

> $name = empty($_POST['name'])? 'some value': trim(&$_POST['name']);